# What is the relationship between ArcMap scale and JPEG width/height?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, scale

Basically I want to automate exporting maps from **a data view** as a 1200x1200 JPEG where the selected feature (one polygon each time) has to be within the inner square and at least one vertex touches the inner gridline (say the square is a size of 1000x1000).

So I want to ask about the relationship between map scale and JPEG width/height so that I can try to calculate the map scale to export and fit in the square.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our format.

Comment: Are you talking about exporting from the data view or layout view?

Comment: from a data view

Comment: How are you exporting the images?

Comment: Please do not include thanks in your posts. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/215590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe there is a direct correlation between the data view scale and your output raster width/height.  The exported image is based on your current display extent.

The image is exported centered on the center of your current extent.  To get the export extent ArcMap will not drop anything from your current extent, so will match your dimensions to fit at least what is displayed on your screen.  The rest it will include to fit your dimensions.  If you change the extent displayed in ArcMap and then export the dimensions will remain the same, but the exported extent will be different.

If you keep the same extent, resize your data frame (resize the ArcMap window), the scale will change but it will export the same extent.  Both of the *output* images below have been exported using width/height of `1200` pixels.  As you can see the outputs are pretty much identical, even though the scale when I exported was quite different.

1:2821 screenshot
[image]

1:2821 output
[image]

1:4589 screenshot
[image]

1:4589 output
[image]

The width/height determines the dimensions of your output image.  Using larger dimensions does not display more of your extent, it just outputs a more detailed image.

> The default values for `df_export_width` and `df_export_height` are 640 and 480. By passing larger values for these parameters, we are able to produce an output image with higher detail.

Possibly the best way to achieve what you want would be to draw your inner square around each polygon, and then use Zoom to Select Feature on each square before exporting to JPG.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Drawing inner squares before exporting is a great idea :)